# What does "exposing a bean" mean?

Tags: java, javabeans

I'm reading around to progressively understand what Beans are, but I don't get this : "A class that exposes two beans" - what does it mean exactly ? That they simply use these beans ? Would you have an example ?
Cheers !

Comment: can you post some references you've read? so as to understand what you mean

Comment: Bean simply means an object that's managed by spring application context. So A  class exposes two beans there are two beans that are created by the spring framework in that class.